# Javascript suggestions not working on VSCode (version 1.72.2)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

It doesn't suggest functions as I type them since updating to version 1.72.2
[image]

Comment: Functionality which provides you the suggestions is called IntelliSense. What you can check is if file in which you code has `.js` extension
Check the documentation on next link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_intellisense

Comment: @niksrb Wasn't the issue, but thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it, was an option in the settings that got disabled as I updated.

Comment: Please elaborate so that if anyone else encounters this issue, they can learn how you solved it. What was the setting? What did it get set to after the update, and what did you revert it to? You can go an extra mile to see if the change is mentioned in release notes, or in any GitHub issues.